# How to find the closed form formula of this sequence

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

How do I find the closed form formula of the below?

$a_0 = −1$

$a_i = −5a_{i−1}$

Comment: I assume you mean $a_i = -5a_{(i-1)}$ and not $a_i = (-5a_i)-1$.   You really need to try harder to typeset things in unambiguous ways.  Now... try writing down the first few terms... surely you can spot a pattern.  It might help to not simplify exponents.

Comment: Thanks @JMoravitz, but this is the exact problem that I've been given to try and solve, hence my confusion.

Comment: I don't understand that comment.  Are you saying that you *did* mean for $a_i=(-5a_i)-1$?  Surely not... *that* problem doesn't deserve to be talked about when discussing sequences since you could just solve it like you would $x=-5x-1$ giving $x=-\frac{1}{6}$.  So then, you must have meant $a_i = -5a_{i-1}$ in which case what is your comment saying?  You phrased that as though I had made an incorrect comment/assumption and that I hadn't understood your question correctly.

Comment: Ok. Thought this place was to be of assistance - NOT to be ridiculed at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should read $a_i=-5a_{i-1}.$

If yes, then we have: $a_0--5^0, a_1=-5a_0=5, a_2=-5a_2=-25=-5^2, ...$

Now show by induction that

$$a_i=(-1)^{i+1}5^i.$$